# How to load picture to picturebox quickly/faster

Tags: mysql, vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010

I have this code to load image from MySql database to picturebox. But it takes about 4-5seconds to load the image.

```vb
' this code if for SAVING IMAGE to MySQL database.
Public Function ConvertToBytes(ByVal img As PictureBox) As Byte()

    Dim msPic As New MemoryStream
    img.Image.Save(msPic, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Dim Mybyte() As Byte = msPic.GetBuffer
    Return Mybyte

End Function

' this code if for RETRIEVING IMAGE FROM MySQL database.

sql_connection = New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conn.connect)
sql_connection.Open()
Dim arrImage() As Byte
sql_command = New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblCatalog WHERE IDCardNo = '" & TEXTBOX1.Text & "'", sql_connection)
sql_command.CommandTimeout = 1000
sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader()
While (sql_reader.Read())
    arrImage = sql_reader("Picture")
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
    PictureBox3.Refresh()
    PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
End While
sql_reader.Close()
```

I place my code into the Timer_tick, I also tried at the button event. But still the result is just the same. Can somebody help me?. I want that when I press enter or click the button, it quickly load the image.

Comment: Then remove the third man in this scenario. Do not store the image in the database but in a (local) custom folder for your application data. By the way how bigger is this image?

Comment: What do you mean "third man?"

Comment: It is a BLOB datatype in database and usually its 200KiB

Comment: Two comments. 1 use sql parameters, you are open to hacking. 2. it's usually better to not save images in a DB. Rather save them to a known folder, put the path/name in the DB, then retrieve the images directly. But the latter may be out of your control.

Comment: @Trevor can you give me links/ tutorials on how to do that? Thanks!